# Python - how to add and condition to str

Tags: python

I have a data frame and want to filter based on the first letter in the column. I want to have all rows that have A or B in that column.
I can do it for one but not sure how to add and to it.

So, my code is

```
df = df[df.typecode.str[0] == 'A']
```

Any combinations of and, || did not work. What do I mise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by many ways-

with **pipe**

```
f = df[(df.typecode.str[0] == 'A') | (df.typecode.str[0] == 'B')]
```

with **startswith**,

```
f = df[df.typecode.str.startswith(tuple(['A','B']))]
```

with **isin**,

```
f = df[df.typecode.str[0].isin(['A', 'B'])]
```

with **in**,

```
f = df[df.typecode.str[0] in ('A', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is:

```
df = df[df.typecode.str[0] in ('A', 'B')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet can also be used. Just a different method. Hope it helps for a broader level of understanding. We are fetching the individual sub dataframes for both `A` and `B` scenarios and concatenate them to form the final Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

dict_frame = {
       "Name" : ["John", "Athul", "Bony", "Becker", "Alfred", "Mithlaj"],
       "Age" : [12, 34, 23, 24, 56, 45]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_frame)
formatted_df = pd.concat([df.loc[df["Name"].str[0] == 'A'],df.loc[df["Name"].str[0] == 'B']])
print(formatted_df)
```

Output

```
     Name  Age
1   Athul   34
4  Alfred   56
2    Bony   23
3  Becker   24
```